# Standard WordPress category feed URL is missing respective posts

Tags: wordpress, rss, categories, feed

I have a site that uses tags and categories and I'm setting up links for RSS feeds for both.

The standard WordPress RSS feed URL format IS working for tags:
example.com/tag/computers/feed

The above will show all the posts in the RSS feed for the 'computers' tag.

However, when I do the same for categories:

example.com/category/west/feed

all I get is an RSS feed with no 'item' tags, that is no posts. I made sure I have posts that have categories assigned to them and that they are published. I tried different categories and have the same result with the feed URL. Here is what all my category feeds look like:

```
<?xml version="null" encoding="null"?>
<rss version="2.0" 
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" . 
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" . 

xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" . 

xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 

xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">

<channel>
<title>MySite</title>
<atom:link href="http://example.com/blogs/category/agile-
commerce/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
 <link>http://example.com</link>
<description>Challenge thinking. Lead change.</description>
<lastBuildDate>Mon, 10 Jul 2017 15:28:33 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<language>en-US</language>
<sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
<generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.8</generator>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: FYI, I also saved the Permalink settings in WordPress to flush them, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: It was the plugin "Category Tag Pages" which allows categories to be assigned to Pages. I disabled the plugin and the WP category feed worked again.